# clip-path dynamic transformations to fill container

Tags: reactjs, math, scale, translate, clip-path

I'm working on a react component I would like to be able to pass any image along with its dimensions, a clip-path calculated from an x, y width, and height for a rectangular region. This part I have working well. Then I would like to scale this clipped region back to fill a div, at the moment I have this div just the original image dimensions to keep it simple. I have the scaling part calculating properly but cannot work out the math to translate the scaled clip-path region. Here is my component (in Typescript):

```
interface RootProps {
  links: Link[];
}

interface RootState {

}

class Root extends React.Component<RootProps, RootState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

    pp = (x: number, y: number): string => {
        return x + "% " + y + "%"
    }


    renderClippedImage = (name: string, x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number) => {
        let iWidth = 600;
        let iHeight = 360;

        let p1 = {
            x: (x / iWidth) * 100,
            y: (y / iHeight) * 100
        }
        let p2 = {
            x: (x / iWidth) * 100,
            y: ((y + height) / iHeight) * 100
        }
        let p3 = {
            x: ((x + width) / iWidth) * 100,
            y: ((y + height) / iHeight) * 100
        }
        let p4 = {
            x: ((x + width) / iWidth) * 100,
            y: (y / iHeight) * 100
        }


        let clipPathString = 'polygon(' +
            this.pp(p1.x, p1.y) + ', ' +
            this.pp(p2.x, p2.y) + ', ' +
            this.pp(p3.x, p3.y) + ', ' +
            this.pp(p4.x, p4.y) + ')';

        let pX = (x) / iWidth;
        let pY = (y) / iHeight;
        let portionCoverageX = (width) / iWidth;
        let portionCoverageY = (height) / iHeight;

        let scaleX = 1;
        let scaleY = 1;
        if (portionCoverageX > 0) {
            scaleX = 1 / portionCoverageX;
        }
        if (portionCoverageY > 0) {
            scaleY = 1 / portionCoverageY;
        }

        let translateX = -(((pX * scaleX) / 2) * 100); //this doesn't work
        let translateY = 0; //similar issues getting this to work

        let pathClipping = {
            WebkitClipPath: clipPathString,
            clipPath: clipPathString,
            transform: 'translateX(' + translateX + '%) translateY(' + translateY + '%) scaleX(' + scaleX + ') scaleY(' + scaleY + ')'
        }

        console.log({
            name: name,
            pX: pX,
            pY: pY,
            portionCoverageX: portionCoverageX,
            portionCoverageY: portionCoverageY,
            scaleX: scaleX,
            scaleY: scaleY,
            translateX: translateX,
            translateY: translateY
        })

        return (
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'lightseagreen' }}>
                <b>{name}</b><br />
                <div style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: 640, height: 360, backgroundColor: 'darkslateblue' }}>
                    <img width="640" height="360" src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" style={pathClipping} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <b>Original</b><br />
                <img width="640" height="360" src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" />
                <br />
                {this.renderClippedImage("one", 80, 100, 200, 100)}
                <br />
                {this.renderClippedImage("two", 50, 50, 150, 100)}
                <br />
                {this.renderClippedImage("three", 300, 10, 300, 340)}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('mount-node'));
```

And here is a codepen, where you can see, my current math actually works for scenario 3, but it needs to work for 1, 2 and any other legitimate region combo as well.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMWGRO

The specific line I think I am strugling with is this:

```
let translateX = (((pX * iWidth) / 2)); //this doesn't work for all examples
```

translateY is a similar issue, any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set `transform-origin` as `top left`, so you can have simpler calculation for transform positions & scale.

```
let scaleX = iWidth / width;
let scaleY = iHeight / height;

let pX = x / iWidth;
let pY = y / iHeight;
let translateX = -pX * 100 * scaleX;
let translateY = -pY * 100 * scaleY;

let pathClipping = {
  WebkitClipPath: clipPathString,
  clipPath: clipPathString,
  transformOrigin: `top left`,
  transform: `
    translate(${translateX}%, ${translateY}%)
    scale(${scaleX}, ${scaleY})
  `
};
```

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ym05nrw3kv) here

Comment: That's it! I see you broke it intentionally with invalid dimensions with another run/example at the end of the codepen, good catch, I plan to handle that other ways. Yes though, that solves my problem, interesting transformOrigin property, hand't even tried to mix that in, but that makes sense.

Comment: Ah so the `if (coverageX > 0)` was your check, right? I forgot to put that back. You can probably do the math to make it work for the default transform origin as well (center) but if it’s not a requirement, it’s much simpler to set it to top left.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I ever handled out or range (such as wider region then source image) values, but that should be easy to add. As you mentioned top left, and your revised math resolved it for me, thanks.